# InDesign: Faster way to resize multiple frames but not images

Tags: adobe-indesign, images, batch-processing

I've used Shift + Cmd to place 48 images into an indesign (cc2014.2) doc. i'd like to change all of the image frame sizes to let's say 9p square, while not affecting the images. how do i do this?

Answer (score 2):

Resize one.

Select the others and choose object>transform again>transform again individually.

Source: [formus.adobe.com](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/835181#expires_in=86399993&token_type=bearer&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dSI6Imltc19uYTEta2V5LTEuY2VyIn0.eyJpZCI6IjE0MjgwNDE3MDI5OTQtNGIzODdlNTEtOTljNi00YWExLTg3MTUtZjM3MDZjZTRhZmVkIiwic2NvcGUiOiJBZG9iZUlELG9wZW5pZCxhZGRpdGlvbmFsX2luZm8uc2NyZWVuX25hbWUsdXBkYXRlX3Byb2ZpbGUuc2NyZWVuX25hbWUiLCJjIjoiSU5neTcwWWptajVyOElUOUlhUm1IZz09Iiwic3RhdGUiOiIiLCJhcyI6Imltcy1uYTEiLCJjcmVhdGVkX2F0IjoiMTQyODA0MTcwMjk5NCIsImV4cGlyZXNfaW4iOiI4NjQwMDAwMCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOiI4NTY4MkNBNzU0ODAzMEFDMEE0Qzk4QTdAQWRvYmVJRCIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImZvcnVtczIiLCJ0eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzX3Rva2VuIn0.cWOUnVtC8f8yM_mMvNald0FC-K2pDRfsPv0vNp3K3VCmHG_KMfbYsCZbfkZBjFFlQ4kmfX6xDwQcqrJVzMIIPngtpSZoCqfIVP7OgP1kROx-6nvYa6mwHrFXoDKbna4vhp-iGV-Pf_p2ValmhGvrQNgTwBtYYKryFrIdEsaW72b0DiYwHl6bh2r4x3VIiwnaGN-4QH1YMJGu9p96XQbAmwev2UVjxbqCttzmK4ghe74wNKJoSAQd694JEnzc0p5Y-AxCK0B1vzoX65ZnuzHVblDVYa0ZX4feK-dyOip8V0l0hhA8VjC5tUE6_yqOpJgXvQn9zNDNg7Ha_KBnaghkaw)

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an excellent solution at least as of CC 2015.

Select multiple objects with **Shift+Click**. Then click & drag a corner or edge of any of the selected items to resize. Hold **Shift** to scale image frames proportionally. Hold **Shift+Ctrl** to scale the frame and the image. This works for grouped items with image frames and text as well.